# An algorithm to tell how many distinct, leading characters are necessary to discern a word from a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, distinct, puzzle

So if you have a list of 50 words, and you want to see how deep into a word a reader must look to be able to count all of the unique words, how would you go about doing that?

I'm basically thinking about loading characters into an array, one-by-one, and then comparing them.  There are so many characters and so many arrays to compare, though.  I wonder what's the most efficient way, if there's already an efficient way out there?

I'm trying to use Javascript, right now.

```
var words = [sort(prompt("Please, insert the word list", "default value in the text field"););];
var encr_int: Number=0;
for (i=0, j=0, maxdif=0; j < word.length; i++) {
    if(word[j].text.charAt(i) == word[j+1].text.charAt(i) AND i > maxdif) {
        maxdif = i;
    }
    else if(word[j].text.charAt(i) != word[j+1].text.charAt(i) {
        j+=1;
    }
    else if(word[j].text.charAt(i) == "") {
        i = 0;
    }
}
document.write(maxdif);
```

Above is my effort at writing the program based on the first answer.

Comment: This is my attempt if you're perhaps interested: http://jsfiddle.net/sBcZa/3/. (It's browser JavaScript; I'm not sure what your `: Number` and `AND` mean.)

Comment: @pimvdb I'm sorry.  I'm still learning Javacript.  I'm on chapter 6 of a book on it called Eloquent Javascript, and I'm probably going to need to read the whole book two or three more times.  "Number" was something that carried over from a paste.

Comment: Does this use a trie or does this use Pointy's solution?

Comment: It's Pointy's solution (look at the sorting, and the `i` and `i + 1` which is the subsequent words checking). I'm not sure if the fiddles helps or causes confusion but I guess it might help :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort the list and then iterate through it, comparing each word with the subsequent word.  Compare with a routine that tells you how many characters had to be checked before a difference was found. Keep track of the maximum "depth" as you go.

*edit* — a function to tell you the "similarity" of two words based on leading characters:

```
function similarity(w1, w2) {
  var i, l = Math.min(w1.length, w2.length);

  for (i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    if (w1[i] !== w2[i]) break;

  return i;
}
```

Comment: Okay, let me try to write it.

Comment: You said "algorithm" so I didn't want to give too much away :-)

Comment: Cool.  Thanks.  Any thoughts on the attempt? :)

Comment: Well I'd break it up with a comparison function.  I can type in something; hold on.

Answer (score 6):

A more efficient approach might be to store your set of words in a trie structure rather than a list. This is a hierarchical structure where each node contains the prefix characters of its children. This means that you don't have to compare against all words - once a certain prefix is found to match words without that prefix need are eliminated.

Although for 50 words speed is not likely to be an issue, the trie will enable you to minimise the number of character comparisons needed and you can keep track of the character count as you recurse down the hierarchy.

If absolute efficiency is a requirement then the precise way in which you organise the trie might become important for example it could be organised to be efficient taking account of the actual statistics of the searches being made against it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the more efficient approach.  If I can figure out how to program it, I'll probably award you the answer.